# How to prevent consumer from creating topic in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using java Spring-Boot framework and trying to prevent our consumer from creating topic in kafka by setting the config properties.

where Configurations are:

From broker side:
`auto.create.topics.enable=true`

From consumer side
`auto.create.topics.enable=false`

for consumer we made auto creation topic `false` where on broker it is `true`.

Above configs are not working for us,
and Also if We have any other ways to archive the same we can discuss.

Answer (score 0):

`auto.create.topics.enable` is not a consumer config. It needs to be `allow.auto.create.topics`, but is only a valid option in `kafka-clients` version 2.3+

There may be other Spring related settings; refer latest comment thread here. [Disable auto topic creation from Spring Kafka Consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73110922/disable-auto-topic-creation-from-spring-kafka-consumer)