# Disable auto topic creation from Spring Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I don't want to auto create topics from my Consumer application when the topics are not present.

I know it is a Kafka server level config to disable auto topic creation (`auto.create.topics.enable = false`), but I cannot do that change in my infrastructure.

So I am looking for a way to disable auto topic creation in my Consumer application (using Spring Kafka).

I tried setting

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        allow.auto.create.topics: false
```

but it is not working!

Seems like Kafka added this support:
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-361%3A+Add+Consumer+Configuration+to+Disable+Auto+Topic+Creation

Can someone please help here?

Comment: Do you have any `NewTopic` beans in your configuration? If so, Spring creates the topics, not Kafka; if not, setting that property should work.

Comment: Doesn't look like your syntax is correct for that additional property. See official Spring Boot docs in YAML mode: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#messaging.kafka.additional-properties

Comment: @ArtemBilan I think it is correct syntax. I can see the property being set in the Consumer config in the logs: `allow.auto.create.topics = false`. Anyways, I tried the syntax that is mentioned in the document, it still does not work.

Comment: @GaryRussell, no I don't have any `NewTopic` beans in my configuration. Could you please point me to the right property that needs to be set?

Comment: Perhaps the topic is auto-created by your producer when you publish?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, I am not running the producer during this test. Producer is down, topics are not present, I bring up the Consumer and the topics get created!

Comment: Since you confirm that option is propagated down to `KafkaConsumer`, then the problem is out of Spring for Apache Kafka project already. Probably you need to narrow down the scope and see if plain Apache Kafka Client sample confirms the problem. Any chances that you can share with us a simple project to reproduce?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, apparently it works correctly with plain Kafka consumer. Here are my Spring Kafka producer and consumer - https://github.com/abhinav-nath/all-about-kafka/tree/master/code/avro-producer-and-consumer. The required `docker-compose.yml` is present in the producer project.

Comment: @ArtemBilan, here is the plain Kafka consumer which works - https://github.com/abhinav-nath/all-about-kafka/blob/master/code/simple-producer-and-consumer/src/main/java/com/codecafe/kafka/consumer/Consumer.java#L39. You can comment out this line to disable the Producer - https://github.com/abhinav-nath/all-about-kafka/blob/master/code/simple-producer-and-consumer/src/main/java/com/codecafe/kafka/RunApp.java#L19 and just run the main program.

Comment: So, what is the concern then? Do you still claim that it doesn't work with Spring for Apache Kafka, but works well with plain Kafka Client?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, yes. It does not work with Spring Kafka for me. I cannot use plain Kafka Client, I have to use Spring Kafka. Could you please help?

Comment: Sure! Let me pull your repo locally. What should I expect with that `allow.auto.create.topics: false` set?

Comment: @ArtemBilan, thanks a ton. Expectation is that Consumer should not create topics if they aren’t already present. I have already told the scenario: Producer is down, Topic is not yet created and when we spin up the Consumer, it should not auto create the topic. Instead it should start-up normally and sit idle till the Producer actually creates the topic.

Comment: Well, it wouldnt be "idle". It should spit out lots of logs saying `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION`

Comment: It is probably hard to show in the comment, but I'll try. I see in the Docker container logs something like: `schema-registry       | [2022-07-25 18:40:05,523] INFO Kafka store reader thread starting consumer (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
schema-registry       | [2022-07-25 18:40:05,529] INFO ConsumerConfig values:
schema-registry       |         allow.auto.create.topics = true`. So, probably the problem really with Schema Registry, but not Spring for Apache Kafka...

Comment: @Abhinav, I've just tried your repo and it seems to be working as expected. 
I've started the docker-compose within the `spring-kafka-producer-and-consumer` folder and run the `SpringKafkaConsumerApplication` (with `allow.auto.create.topics: false`). The Kafdrop console shows no other topics but the `__consumer_offsets` and my application logs spits warnings like: `org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : ... Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 14 : {test-topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}`

If I enable the `allow.auto.create.topics: true` then the `test-topic` is created.

Comment: @tzolov, that's correct. I created simple Spring Kafka producer and consumer last night to test just Spring Kafka's behaviour and it works quite well. Now I am realising that the problem might be in `@RetryableTopic`. I am posting the details in another comment. Please have a look.

Comment: @tzolov, @ArtemBilan, @GaryRussell, @TomazFernandes - This seems to be an issue in either `@RetryableTopic` or `@DltHandler`. This property `allow.auto.create.topics: false` doesn't work when these annotations are used. It works when I comment both the annotations. Here is the repo to reproduce it - https://github.com/abhinav-nath/all-about-kafka/tree/master/code/consumer-error-handling/fixed-backoff-with-single-retry-topic. Required `docker-compose.yml` is present in the root directory.

Comment: @Abhinav,  the `@RetryableTopic` exposes a `autoCreateTopics` property that defaults to "true".  Can you set it to false and try again. 
The javadocs makes it clear that this property is handled independently from the Kafka Configs: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/f4b73afd53f9fa9b178120f4e9b1bd0a3e200a43/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/annotation/RetryableTopic.java#L104

Comment: @tzolov, thanks a lot! It worked. It is a bit strange though. When `autoCreateTopics` is `"true"` and `allow.auto.create.topics: false`, the Consumer still creates all three topics - the `main` topic, the `-retry` topic and the `-dlt` topic. When `autoCreateTopics` is `"false"` and `allow.auto.create.topics: true` then also the Consumer creates all three topics. It seems like an "OR" condition between both the flags. Only setting them both to `false` prevents the Consumer from creating any topic. Not sure why there are two separate flags.

Comment: I have summarised the solution and posted it as an answer. Please upvote and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The below configuration in `application.yml` works perfectly for Consumers based on Spring for Apache Kafka:

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        allow.auto.create.topics: false
```

[Here](https://github.com/abhinav-nath/all-about-kafka/tree/master/code/spring-kafka-producer-and-consumer/spring-kafka-consumer) is a reference project for a simple Spring Kafka Consumer.

However in my case, I was also using the **non-blocking retries** provided by Spring Kafka in the form of `@RetryableTopic` annotation.

In this case in order to turn off auto topic creation from the Consumer, along with the above mentioned property change, we also need to set a property named `autoCreateTopics` to `"false"` in the `@RetryableTopic` annotation like so:

```java
  @RetryableTopic(
    attempts = "4",
    backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000),
    fixedDelayTopicStrategy = FixedDelayStrategy.SINGLE_TOPIC,
    autoCreateTopics = "false"
  )
```

It's default value is `"true"`.

[Here](https://github.com/abhinav-nath/all-about-kafka/tree/master/code/consumer-error-handling/fixed-backoff-with-single-retry-topic) is a reference project for Spring Kafka Consumer with non-blocking retries.

Big thanks to [tzolov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4430769/tzolov) for pointing me to the right direction.